# Why Would Spacing Matter in grub.conf?

Tags: centos, grub

See my [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148327/grub-not-recognizing-xen-kernel-on-boot/148537#148537).

GRUB wouldn't recognize the XEN kernel until extra blank lines were added and the title of the GRUB entry matched the version of XEN installed on the server.

I've always considered the `title` line to represent a label for the entry, and I never would have thought spacing would have mattered.  Is there a code style guideline/wiki for GRUB with CentOS to avoid these types of issues in the future?